# how to use realm to save an array of NSURL？

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

Now, I have a realm model , including images, audios and others. So I have to get the URLs of the media files and give the model value of the URLs. But I meet a problem that I cannot save them into the realm. Because I can not save NSArray , also when I use the RLMArray to contain them ,it also don't be solved. So how can I give my model the URLs?

Comment: like you have "www.abc.com/imagename.png" & you want to save it?

Comment: yes, I want to give it to the Realm model .

Comment: So, save as String, rather than URL, and later at runtime, make URL from String. 

If you show me your model, I can help you better.

Comment: YES I know the NSString is better, but problem is I might have URLs more than one, the array , RLMArray , cannot receive it. The NSArray cannot use in the realm model definitely. So how can I do? `@property RLMArray<NSString *> * photos;

@property RLMArray<NSString *> * audios;` if like this, It will crash when I run the app.

Answer (score 2):

Its not possilbe to directly add the NSURL type in Realm but you can use workaround on your own like :-

```
@interface MyModel : JOBIBaseModel

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * urlString;

-(NSURL *)getUrl;

@end

@implementation MyModel

-(NSURL *)getUrl{
    return [NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString];
}

@end
```

Then access it from your object like:-

```
NSURL *url=Obj.getUrl;
```

## Update for array

```
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(MyArrayModel);
@interface MyArrayModel : JOBIBaseModel
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * urlString;
-(NSURL *)getUrl;
@end

@implementation MyArrayModel
-(NSURL *)getUrl{
    return [NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString];
}
@end

@interface MyModel : JOBIBaseModel
@property (nonatomic, strong) RLMArray <MyArrayModel> * strings;
@end

@implementation MyModel

@end
```

And use it like:-

```
NSURL *url=Obj.strings[0].getUrl;
```